# how to use tap property of cardImage interface in bot framework version 4 javascript

Tags: javascript, botframework

how to use tap property of cardImage interface in bot framework version 4 javascript.

```
var   card1 = CardFactory.heroCard( 'title',
                'sub title',
               CardImage.tap.CardFactory.actions([{
                type: 'openUrl',
                title: moreinfo,
                value: MapImage
                 }])
                );
```

I want to show an image with map so that user can able to tap the image for location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make use of Card Factory for this. A simple example of how to use the tap property is shown below. You can implement your requirement based on the same.

```
createHeroCard() {
    return CardFactory.heroCard(
        'BotFramework Hero Card',
        'Hello World!',
        CardFactory.images(['http://localhost:3978/assets/dog.jpg']),
        CardFactory.actions([
            {
                type: 'openUrl',
                title: 'openUrl',
                value: 'https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bot-service/'
            },{
                type: 'postBack',
                title: 'postBack',
                value: 'postBack'
            },{
                type: 'imBack',
                title: 'imBack',
                value: 'imBack'
            }]),
        { tap: { type: ActionTypes.OpenUrl, title: 'Tap Action', value: 'https://microsoft.com '}}
    );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi I am facing similar issue and came across this post.
After adding the above hero card code to preview section. Title, subtitle and description are coming up for me in hero card. However actions/buttons are not showing up on hero card. And changes for tap action are also not reflecting. Is there anything else that needs to be done.